# How to give PHP exec() read/write privileges

Tags: php, exec

I can't get exec() to read or write how I need it to:

`exec("php -f /root/script/screenshot.php")`

Fails with `Could not open input file`. Must be a permissions problem. Changing the file owner to the php user didn't fix it though.

Can't get this to work either:

`exec("xvfb-run -a cutycapt --min-width=1920 --min-height=1920 --url='{$url}' --out='{$path}'");`

Fails but doesn't give any error message. cutycapt is a screenshot app to take a screenshot of a website.

Both commands work perfectly from command-line. But it seems that php exec() will neither read nor write files...

Comment: Are we talking about command-line PHP or some complex set-up that involves a web server?

Comment: The exec commands are in php scripts executed by the apache web server.

Comment: Then you have it. Apache typically starts as root (so it can bind privileged ports) but then forks as unprivileged user (to reduce potential risks, being a service open to the world).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that it was indeed a permissions error. The second command wasn't working because the folder didn't have write permissions to the apache user.

`exec("xvfb-run -a cutycapt --min-width=1920 --min-height=1920 --url='{$url}' --out='{$path}'");`

Changed the permissions, and now the above command is saving screenshots no problem at all.

Comment: Where can i see and get all the permissions of an exe and what they mean ?? Cause i need to run an exec too

Answer (score 0):

watch if your folder path is in the sudoers file

Comment: Nope, not in sudoers file.

Comment: then take that path in sudoers file and it will work